# Filtering An Array according to several keys

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of people with certain information about them.

 I want to filter this array according to religion, gender, and record number at the same time.
Is there a way to do?

Here is **PEOPLE** Array:

```
{
    "Id": 1270,
    "FirstName": "name",
    "LastName": "last name",
    "Religion": "religion",
    "RecordNumber": 1,
    "Gender": "male",
    "Contacted": false,
    "NeedsTransportation": false,
    "WhenContacted": null,
    "ContactedByWho": null,
    },
     {
     "Id": 1383,
     "FirstName": "name",
     "LastName": "last name",
     "Religion": "religion",
     "RecordNumber": 1,
     "Gender": "male",
     "Contacted": false,
     "NeedsTransportation": false,
     "WhenContacted": null,
     "ContactedByWho": null
    },
    {
     "Id": 1394,
     "FirstName": "name",
     "LastName": "last name",
     "Religion": "religion",
     "RecordNumber": 1,
     "Gender": "male",
     "Contacted": false,
     "NeedsTransportation": false,
     "WhenContacted": null,
     "ContactedByWho": null,
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: I guess you could do this with RxJS: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Comment: What you've got there is not an array, for starters ...

Comment: Oscar it is I just took a part of it to demonstrate

Comment: `const temp = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
        return d.Religion.indexOf(val) !== -1  || d.Gender.indexOf(val) !== -1;
      });
      this.people= temp;`

Comment: this.temp is this.voters, I want it to filter accordingly. After I filter gender it filters religion depends on the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```
const people: Person[] = [...];
people.filter(p => {
   return p.Religion === (...) // condition for religion
       && p.Gender === (...) // condition for gender
       && p.RecordNumber === (...); // condition for record number
});
```

Of course the conditions needn't be equality comparisons, and neither you've got to use AND operators. The idea is that the `filter` method will return a new array containing only those items for which the function passed as an argument returns `true`. Inside you can make any checks you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just do `filter`.

```
 var filteredResult =   x.filter((x)=> (x.Id == 1394) && (x.Religion =="religion") && (x.Gender=="male") )
```

Of course, you can use any operator which can give you a boolean true for the item you are iterating to get that item in the result array

Answer (score 1):

```js
let people = [{
    "Id": 1270,
    "FirstName": "name",
    "LastName": "last name",
    "Religion": "religion",
    "RecordNumber": 1,
    "Gender": "male",
    "Contacted": false,
    "NeedsTransportation": false,
    "WhenContacted": null,
    "ContactedByWho": null,
    },
     {
     "Id": 1383,
     "FirstName": "name",
     "LastName": "last name",
     "Religion": "religion",
     "RecordNumber": 1,
     "Gender": "male",
     "Contacted": false,
     "NeedsTransportation": false,
     "WhenContacted": null,
     "ContactedByWho": null
    },
    {
     "Id": 1394,
     "FirstName": "name",
     "LastName": "last name",
     "Religion": "christian",
     "RecordNumber": 1,
     "Gender": "male",
     "Contacted": false,
     "NeedsTransportation": false,
     "WhenContacted": null,
     "ContactedByWho": null,
    }]
    

const FILTER = (RELIGION, GENDER, RECORD_NUMBER) => {
  return people.filter(({Religion, Gender, RecordNumber}) => Religion === RELIGION && Gender === GENDER && +RecordNumber === +RECORD_NUMBER)
}
   
let filteredPeople = FILTER('christian', 'male', 1)
   
console.log(filteredPeople)
```

I prepend the `+` operator before the `RecordNumber && RECORD_NUMBER` arguments incase it is passed as a String e.g `+'1' === 1`